# ANDROID: Check if incoming SMS number exist in a custom list filled with different phone formats

Tags: android, parsing, sms, format

I have always used this site as a spectator and I have always found the answers I was looking for, but I need something more detailed this time I hope you can give me a hand.

Problem: I need to check if the sms incoming number is present within a custom list.
I have already created and tested the broadcast receiver and i get the correct number in international format (es. +333401234567). The problem is that the list that the user can create is taken from his contacts in the address book that can be written in many different formats.

I have read about the libphonenumber but I can not figure out if it's right for me because I 
can not predict the identification code of the country or maybe i do not understood well how it works.

I think I should use a method similar to this, which controls the existence of the incoming number on the address book, but adapt it to a customized list:

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
        /// number is the phone number
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
        PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
        Uri.encode(number));
        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
           if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
              return true;
        }
        } finally {
        if (cur != null)
           cur.close();
        }
        return false;
        }
```

The xml file that contains the saved information is in the format below,every ContactRow item is loaded and added in a custom List.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <ContactRow>
    <id>16</id>
    <name>Dave Smith</name>
    <number>3401234567</number>
    <photo_id>0</photo_id>
  </ContactRow>
    <id>18</id>
    <name>John Snow</name>
    <number>+33 348 123 4567</number>
    <photo_id>0</photo_id>
  </ContactRow>
</root>
```

I load this XML file here:

```
public class ReadXmlFile {

    private List<ContactRow> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactRow>();


    public ReadXmlFile(File xmlFile){

        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        try {
                if (xmlFile.exists()){
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(xmlFile.getPath());

                doc = db.parse(is);

                NodeList nl_ContactRow = doc.getElementsByTagName("ContactRow");

                for (int i = 0; i < nl_ContactRow.getLength(); i++) {

                    String id = "error";
                    String name = "error";
                    String number = "error";
                    long photo_id =-1;
                    Bitmap photo = null;

                    Node n_ContactRow = nl_ContactRow.item(i);
                    NodeList CR_childs  = n_ContactRow.getChildNodes();

                    for (int j = 0; j < CR_childs.getLength(); j++) {
                         Node child = CR_childs.item(j);

                         if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("id"))     id = child.getTextContent();
                         if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name"))   name = child.getTextContent();
                         if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("number"))     number = child.getTextContent();
                         if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("photo_id"))   photo_id = Long.parseLong(child.getTextContent());
                    }

                    try{
                        ContactRow CR = new ContactRow(id, name, number, photo_id, photo);
                            contactList.add(CR);
                            Log.i("davide","ADD Contact LOAD DOM: "+name);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        exc.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("davide","AddContactRow: getDomElement: "+e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("davide","AddContactRow: getDomElement: "+e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("davide","AddContactRow: getDomElement: "+e);
        }
    }

}
```

All this code works properly, i need only to check if the saved numbers (in different format) exist in my custom list.

I can add addictional information when the contact is picked from the address book if this can help later.

Thanks for your help,
Davide